# read only file system?

Tags: 12.04

I'm running a kernel of ubuntu on my acer chromebook and I put some music on my MP3 and it worked fine. Next time I try it says error opening file :Read only file system. I am so confused any help would be appreciated!

When I run `dmesg` I get this.

```
[    0.235869] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 11 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff]
[    0.235874] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 12 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff]
[    0.235878] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 13 [mem 0x000dc000-0x000dffff]
[    0.235882] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 14 [mem 0x000e0000-0x000e3fff]
[    0.235886] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 15 [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff]
[    0.235890] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 16 [mem 0x000e8000-0x000ebfff]
[    0.235894] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 17 [mem 0x000ec000-0x000effff]
[    0.235898] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 18 [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.235902] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 19 [mem 0x7ea00001-0xfebfffff]
[    0.235906] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 20 [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed44fff]
[    0.235911] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xe0400000-0xe04fffff]
[    0.235915] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xe0600000-0xe06fffff]
[    0.235920] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xe0500000-0xe05fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.235998] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.236084] IP route cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.236355] TCP established hash table entries: 262144 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
[    0.237661] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[    0.238732] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 262144 bind 65536)
[    0.238737] TCP: reno registered
[    0.238748] UDP hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 98304 bytes)
[    0.238799] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 98304 bytes)
[    0.238953] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.238994] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[    0.239164] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    0.239236] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.239241] Placing 64MB software IO TLB between ffff880075800000 - ffff880079800000
[    0.239245] software IO TLB at phys 0x75800000 - 0x79800000
[    0.240192] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
[    0.240203] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x10, revision=0x28
[    0.240246] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[    0.244120] msgmni has been set to 3742
[    0.244550] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    0.244555] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.244559] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.244645] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.244822] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.245041] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.245211] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.245215] pci 0000:01:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.245224] pcie_pme 0000:00:1c.0:pcie01: service driver pcie_pme loaded
[    0.245258] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.245262] pci 0000:02:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.245266] pci 0000:02:00.1: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
[    0.245274] pcie_pme 0000:00:1c.1:pcie01: service driver pcie_pme loaded
[    0.245299] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.245336] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.245905] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    0.246267] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    0.246426] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    0.246504] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
[    0.246511] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    0.246590] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
[    0.246596] ACPI: Sleep Button [TPAD]
[    0.246678] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[    0.246684] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.247251] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
[    0.247260] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    0.247310] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[    0.247656] Monitor-Mwait will be used to enter C-1 state
[    0.247690] Monitor-Mwait will be used to enter C-2 state
[    0.247723] Monitor-Mwait will be used to enter C-3 state
[    0.247748] ACPI: acpi_idle registered with cpuidle
[    0.253186] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
[    0.253191] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THRM] (0 C)
[    0.256219] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    0.256292] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.256394] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel Sandybridge Chipset
[    0.256537] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 2097152K total, 262144K mappable
[    0.257691] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected 32768K stolen memory
[    0.257951] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0xd0000000
[    0.258204] tpm_tis tpm_tis: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xFE, rev-id 71)
[    0.265869] [Firmware Bug]: battery: (dis)charge rate invalid.
[    0.265938] ACPI: Battery Slot [BATX] (battery present)
[    0.301023] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    0.301425] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.372248] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.372264] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[    0.372268] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    0.698271] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[    0.794057] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.097818] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    1.105005] fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    1.105007] drm: registered panic notifier
[    1.105022] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.106170] loop: module loaded
[    1.106246] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    1.106332] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.106381] ahci: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[    1.106413] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    1.106420] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck stag pm led clo pio slum part apst 
[    1.106429] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.106992] scsi0 : ahci
[    1.107128] scsi1 : ahci
[    1.107233] scsi2 : ahci
[    1.107336] scsi3 : ahci
[    1.107477] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xe0705000 port 0xe0705100 irq 43
[    1.107481] ata2: DUMMY
[    1.107483] ata3: DUMMY
[    1.107486] ata4: DUMMY
[    1.107634] hso: /build/x86-mario/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/chromeos-kernel-3.4-r996/work/chromeos-kernel-3.4/drivers/net/usb/hso.c: Option Wireless
[    1.107663] usbcore: registered new interface driver hso
[    1.107742] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.107788] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.107794] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.107888] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.107927] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
[    1.111832] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.111856] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: irq 21, io mem 0xe0705800
[    1.116971] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.117013] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.117020] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.117025] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.117030] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.4.0 ehci_hcd
[    1.117034] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.117211] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.117219] hub 1-0:1.0: 7 ports detected
[    1.117353] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    1.117359] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.117422] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.117460] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    1.121353] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    1.121377] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 19, io mem 0xe0705c00
[    1.126971] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.127009] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.127015] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.127021] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.127025] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.4.0 ehci_hcd
[    1.127030] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.127183] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.127190] hub 2-0:1.0: 11 ports detected
[    1.127320] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.127339] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.127384] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[    1.127388] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[    1.127392] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    1.127422] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.127425] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    1.127456] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    1.127474] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-realtek
[    1.127510] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    1.127528] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    1.127542] USB Serial support registered for generic
[    1.127547] usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
[    1.127610] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.127614] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    1.134157] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.134273] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.137481] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.137510] device-mapper: verity: version 0.1.0 loaded
[    1.137514] device-mapper: verity-chromeos: dm-verity-chromeos registered
[    1.137593] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    1.137691] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    1.137758] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.137761] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.182751] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input5
[    1.217140] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.242040] Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 1097.506 MHz.
[    1.242050] Switching to clocksource tsc
[    1.245326] cyapa 7-0067: Cypress APA Trackpad Information:
[    1.245329]     Product ID:  CYTRA-103002-00
[    1.245330]     Protocol Generation:  3
[    1.245332]     Firmware Version:  1.9
[    1.245333]     Hardware Version:  1.0
[    1.245335]     Max ABS X,Y:   870,470
[    1.245336]     Physical Size X,Y:   87,47
[    1.245447] input: cyapa as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/i2c-7/7-0067/input/input6
[    1.250293] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
[    1.250330] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[    1.250521] ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
[    1.250742] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    1.250783] TCP: cubic registered
[    1.250786] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.251041] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.251391] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.252924]   Magic number: 14:245:715
[    1.253433] ALSA device list:
[    1.253437]   No soundcards found.
[    1.256655] ata1.00: ATA-8: ST320LT020-9YG142, 0010SDM1, max UDMA/133
[    1.256666] ata1.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[    1.259173] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.259540] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST320LT020-9YG14 0010 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.259801] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[    1.259809] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.259905] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.259910] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.259938] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.341766] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[    1.341838]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10 sda11 sda12
[    1.344042] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.344056] dm: attempting early device configuration.
[    1.344430] device-mapper: init: adding target '0 1740800 verity payload=ROOT_DEV hashtree=HASH_DEV hashstart=1740800 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=98f86b8807863f8f73293eea0c0f1810da67d11a salt=9b5a1d53330cf997edaf2646b2f837f16df4a439e3a78905b01bc92413bdb117'
[    1.344447] device-mapper: verity: Argument 0: 'payload=ROOT_DEV'
[    1.344453] device-mapper: verity: Argument 1: 'hashtree=HASH_DEV'
[    1.344467] device-mapper: verity: Argument 2: 'hashstart=1740800'
[    1.344471] device-mapper: verity: Argument 3: 'alg=sha1'
[    1.344475] device-mapper: verity: Argument 4: 'root_hexdigest=98f86b8807863f8f73293eea0c0f1810da67d11a'
[    1.344480] device-mapper: verity: Argument 5: 'salt=9b5a1d53330cf997edaf2646b2f837f16df4a439e3a78905b01bc92413bdb117'
[    1.419083] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    1.533546] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.533556] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.534017] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.534205] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.637078] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    1.751755] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.751766] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.752234] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.752451] hub 2-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.826221] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[    1.844992] device-mapper: verity: Failed to acquire device 'ROOT_DEV': -1
[    1.845022] device-mapper: table: 254:0: verity: Device lookup failed
[    1.845031] dm: starting dm-0 (vroot) failed
[    1.913577] usb 1-1.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[    1.913591] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04ca, idProduct=3006
[    1.913599] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.917623] EXT3-fs (sda7): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    1.928771] EXT2-fs (sda7): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (244)
[    1.935490] EXT4-fs (sda7): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    1.935500] EXT4-fs (sda7): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    1.987333] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[    2.126006] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=064e, idProduct=d251
[    2.126016] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.126022] usb 1-1.3: Product: HD WebCam
[    2.126027] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: SuYin
[    2.126032] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: HF1016-A21U-OV02-VA-R01.00.03
[    2.202141] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[    2.292999] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745
[    2.293009] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.293016] usb 2-1.4: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0
[    2.293021] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    2.295733] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input7
[    2.296201] generic-usb 0003:045E:0745.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
[    2.301834] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input8
[    2.302422] generic-usb 0003:045E:0745.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
[    2.318485] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.2/input/input9
[    2.319203] generic-usb 0003:045E:0745.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Nano Transceiver v2.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input2
[    5.823647] EXT4-fs (sda7): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    5.823667] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3513
[    5.823802] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3611
[    5.823952] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 272365
[    5.824109] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3623
[    5.824149] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3622
[    5.824180] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3621
[    5.824210] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3619
[    5.824241] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3609
[    5.824271] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3608
[    5.824301] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3582
[    5.824332] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3569
[    5.824363] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3562
[    5.854779] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3535
[    5.854898] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3566
[    5.854924] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3544
[    5.854950] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3524
[    5.854978] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3523
[    5.855001] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3505
[    5.855025] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3589
[    5.855086] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 271982
[    5.897299] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 271340
[    5.897371] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3575
[    5.897397] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3606
[    5.897420] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3616
[    5.897443] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3615
[    5.897469] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3357
[    5.897493] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3614
[    5.897516] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3613
[    5.897538] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3612
[    5.897560] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3601
[    5.897582] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3607
[    5.897603] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3610
[    5.897626] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3587
[    5.931076] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1100
[    5.931167] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3605
[    5.931193] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3602
[    5.931217] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3600
[    5.931240] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3598
[    5.931262] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3590
[    5.931284] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3588
[    5.931306] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3592
[    5.931328] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 3593
[    5.970752] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 276998
[    5.970876] EXT4-fs (sda7): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 272028
[    5.970903] EXT4-fs (sda7): 44 orphan inodes deleted
[    5.970907] EXT4-fs (sda7): recovery complete
[    6.164026] EXT4-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.164067] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 8:7.
[    6.178507] devtmpfs: mounted
[    6.182131] Freeing unused kernel memory: 624k freed
[    6.182296] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 8192k
[    6.193659] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1652k freed
[    6.195935] Freeing unused kernel memory: 264k freed
[    6.740671] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    6.740732] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    6.832606] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    6.832689] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    6.851637] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    6.851710] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    6.852703] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    6.852754] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[   17.156857] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[   17.156930] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[   17.162739] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[   17.162811] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[   17.174036] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[   17.174109] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[   18.176603] udevd[142]: starting version 175
[   18.290725] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   18.291168] tg3.c:v3.123 (March 21, 2012)
[   18.291524] nm10_gpio version 0.04 built on Aug 26 2012 at 19:06:30
[   18.291539] gpiochip_find_base: found new base at 160
[   18.291585] gpiochip_add: registered GPIOs 160 to 255 on device: 0000:00:1f.0
[   18.301400] init: plymouth main process (65) killed by SEGV signal
[   18.301922] init: plymouth-splash main process (200) terminated with status 2
[   18.312271] rtc_cmos 00:08: RTC can wake from S4
[   18.314151] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[   18.314156] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[   18.349612] rtc_cmos 00:08: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[   18.349658] rtc0: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[   18.372489] tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM57785) rev 57785100] (PCI Express) MAC address b8:88:e3:d7:30:2d
[   18.372523] tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
[   18.372533] tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
[   18.372539] tg3 0000:02:00.0: eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
[   18.372737] sdhci-pci 0000:02:00.1: SDHCI controller found [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
[   18.372772] sdhci-pci 0000:02:00.1: Invalid iomem size. You may experience problems.
[   18.373013] Registered led device: mmc0::
[   18.374515] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:02:00.1] using ADMA
[   18.382774] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   18.394832] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[   18.394840] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a
[   18.394843] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   18.394849] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   18.394852] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a
[   18.401573] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   18.401612] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   18.401616] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.401621] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.401625] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.401640] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.404824] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'ath9k_rate_control'
[   18.405498] Registered led device: ath9k-phy0
[   18.405509] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9462 Rev:2 mem=0xffffc90014f80000, irq=17
[   18.413174] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   18.457524] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   18.460063] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD WebCam (064e:d251)
[   18.468932] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   18.468938] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   18.700280] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   18.700286] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   18.700293] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   18.700298] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   18.700303] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   18.700308] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   18.700312] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   18.744712] udevd[160]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth1
[   18.966322] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[   18.966455] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   18.966590] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[   18.966717] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[   18.966946] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[   20.078996] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   20.350512] init: plymouth-log main process (543) terminated with status 1
[   20.351908] init: failsafe main process (545) killed by TERM signal
[   20.417195] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (584) terminated with status 1
[   20.435479] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.435485] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   20.746137] ieee80211 phy0: device now idle
[   20.749960] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   20.760725] tg3 0000:02:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   20.760738] tg3 0000:02:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   20.760747] tg3 0000:02:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   21.325057] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   21.341951] ieee80211 phy0: device no longer idle - scanning
[   22.347298] fuse init (API version 7.18)
[   26.001399] ieee80211 phy0: device now idle
[   26.042838] ieee80211 phy0: device no longer idle - scanning
[   29.924170] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82
[   29.924185] ieee80211 phy0: Allocated STA 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82
[   29.927953] ieee80211 phy0: Inserted STA 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82
[   29.927961] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 (try 1/3)
[   29.929945] wlan0: authenticated
[   29.929954] wlan0: moving STA 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 to state 2
[   29.934204] wlan0: associate with 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 (try 1/3)
[   29.938514] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[   29.938522] wlan0: associated
[   29.938550] wlan0: moving STA 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 to state 3
[   29.938561] ieee80211 phy0: WMM queue=2 aci=0 acm=0 aifs=3 cWmin=15 cWmax=1023 txop=0 uapsd=0
[   29.938571] ieee80211 phy0: WMM queue=3 aci=1 acm=0 aifs=7 cWmin=15 cWmax=1023 txop=0 uapsd=0
[   29.938579] ieee80211 phy0: WMM queue=1 aci=2 acm=0 aifs=2 cWmin=7 cWmax=15 txop=94 uapsd=0
[   29.938587] ieee80211 phy0: WMM queue=0 aci=3 acm=0 aifs=2 cWmin=3 cWmax=7 txop=47 uapsd=0
[   29.941856] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   29.943217] wlan0: dropped frame to 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 (unauthorized port)
[   29.962375] wlan0: moving STA 00:18:e7:f5:e4:82 to state 4
[   40.182929] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Comment: run `dmesg` and see if there was an error that caused the filesystem to be remounted read-only.

Comment: What would signify that there is an error?

Comment: A message saying there was an error and the filesystem was remounted read-only...

Comment: I did get this one line that looks like what your talking about.   [   15.989873] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Comment: And what are the lines leading up to that?  Edit your question and add the additional information there.

Comment: Looks like you are out of space on your hard drive or the MP3 player.  Can you post the output of `df -h` while the MP3 player is plugged in?